# Bootstrap-can't change nav-bar logo size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I set the logo with :

```
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img id="logo" class="no-opacity" src="images/logo.png"></a>
```

I set the size with :

```
.navbar-brand
{

  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height:10px;
  left: 10px;

}
```

The logo stay huge, can't make it smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the css to a class on the img-tag, it should work.

Comment: like this ? .navbar-brand.img ?

Comment: Or make a class called "logo" and use it on the img-element. Then the css will be applied to .logo. You could also just use to "no-opacity" class which already exists on the img element.